# fill command cannot be used

Tags: c#, dataset, oledb, fill

This Is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;
//db con
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace SOMaintenance.App_Code {
    public class readdata {
        string sConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        public void selectdata(DataSet dataset1, string sqlcommand) {
            string strConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SOConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConString);
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM USERMASTER", conn);
            cmd.Fill(dataset1);
            conn.Open();
            OleDbDataReader dr;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know why `cmd.Fill(dataset1);` cannot be used. It's telling me to add `system.data.oledb.command` but when I add the problem remains the same.
Can anyone help on this?

Comment: you can call `con.Open()` before `fill`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("USERMASTER");  
using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(sConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    var queryString = "SELECT * FROM USERMASTER";
    using (var comm = new OleDbCommand(queryString, conn))
    {
        using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter (comm))
        {
            da.Fill(dataTable);
            return dataTable;
        }
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```